# I'm having issues trying to convert my StatelessWidget code..why?

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean, stateless, stateful

I was trying to code a stateful widget on a statelessWidget class to put a bool and a stateState((), (show or hide password). So I followed some post which said that the solution is to convert.

I converted my class and I have some errors, maybe I should update my code but I don't know how to do that and I'm always getting errors like this:

**36:32: Error: The setter '_isSecret' isn't defined for the class '_RoundedPasswordFieldState'.
-'_RoundedPasswordFieldState' is from 'package:yona/Login/Components/rounded_password_field.dart' ('lib/Login/Components/rounded_password_field.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named '_isSecret'.**

Can you help me please ?
The problem is resolved, this is the new code

```
class _RoundedPasswordFieldState extends State<RoundedPasswordField> {
bool _isSecret = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return TextFieldContainer(
   child: TextFormField(
     obscureText: _isSecret,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
       hintText: "Password",
       border: InputBorder.none,
       icon: Icon(
         Icons.lock,
         color: DarkTurquoise,
       ),
       suffixIcon: InkWell(
         onTap: () =>
             setState(() => _isSecret = !_isSecret),
         child: Icon(!_isSecret
             ? Icons.visibility
             : Icons.visibility_off, color: DarkTurquoise),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is resolved:

Answer (score 0):

To access `_isSecret`, you need to use `widget.`:

```
class RoundedPasswordField extends StatefulWidget {
final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;

const RoundedPasswordField({
 required this.onChanged,
 Key? key,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
_RoundedPasswordFieldState createState() => _RoundedPasswordFieldState();
}


class _RoundedPasswordFieldState extends State<RoundedPasswordField> {

bool _isSecret = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return TextFieldContainer(
   child: TextFormField(
     obscureText:_isSecret,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
       hintText: "Password",
       icon: Icon(
         Icons.lock,
         color: DarkTurquoise,
       ),
       suffixIcon: InkWell(
         onTap: () =>
             setState(() => _isSecret = !_isSecret),
         child: Icon(!_isSecret
             ? Icons.visibility
             : Icons.visibility_off),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
}
}
```

Comment: I wrote like this but I have this error : Static field '_isSecret' can't be accessed through an instance.  Try using the class 'RoundedPasswordField' to access the field.

Comment: Why do you have static? Remove it.

Comment: It was recommend by flutter if I don't pu this I have errors everywhere especially in `const RoundedPasswordField` I have this error "Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields.  Try making all of the fields final, or removing the keyword 'const' from the constructor."

Comment: It's not recommended by flutter. I edited my answer, check it out. Move it down to the widget level, and declare it locally, because you aren't depending on it from the top.

Comment: What do you mean by declare locally ? I followed you editing answer but still have red underlined code under _isSecret with these errors "The setter '_isSecret' isn't defined for the type 'RoundedPasswordField'.  Try importing the library that defines '_isSecret', correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named '_isSecret'."

Comment: remove `widget.` in your setState.

Comment: it worked for the _isSecret in my setState, I have 3 errors left with my `!Rounded passwordfield._isSecret` I tried to remove "Roundedpasswordfield and my code is running but the function show or hide the password with the icon visibility doesn't work

Comment: remove `RoundedPasswordField` from your setState and afterwards, you don't need it.

Comment: I edited my answer, just copy it as is, and it'll work. Read the documentation, you need to understand these things.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time ! All is working right now !! You are a saver

Comment: You're most welcome, please mark it as the correct answer to your post.

Answer (score 0):

in setState you should change `_isSecret` to `RoundedPasswordField._isSecret` and the other problem is you are not calling onChanged.

working code:

```
class RoundedPasswordField extends StatefulWidget {
static bool _isSecret = true;
final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;

const RoundedPasswordField({
 required this.onChanged,
 Key? key,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
_RoundedPasswordFieldState createState() => _RoundedPasswordFieldState();
}


class _RoundedPasswordFieldState extends State<RoundedPasswordField> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return TextFieldContainer(
   child: TextFormField(
     obscureText: RoundedPasswordField._isSecret,
     onChanged: widget.onChanged,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
       hintText: "Password",
       icon: Icon(
         Icons.lock,
         color: DarkTurquoise,
       ),
       suffixIcon: InkWell(
         onTap: () =>
             setState(() => RoundedPasswordField._isSecret = !RoundedPasswordField._isSecret),
         child: Icon(!RoundedPasswordField._isSecret
             ? Icons.visibility
             : Icons.visibility_off),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
}
}
```

If you don't want to change _isSecret from outside of your widget then just use this code

```
class RoundedPasswordField extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;

  const RoundedPasswordField({
    required this.onChanged,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RoundedPasswordFieldState createState() => _RoundedPasswordFieldState();
}

class _RoundedPasswordFieldState extends State<RoundedPasswordField> {
  bool _isSecret = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFieldContainer(
      child: TextFormField(
        obscureText: _isSecret,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Password",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.lock,
            color: DarkTurquoise,
          ),
          suffixIcon: InkWell(
            onTap: () => setState(() => _isSecret =
                !_isSecret),
            child: Icon(!_isSecret
                ? Icons.visibility
                : Icons.visibility_off),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```